# php formulario con mysql

Tags: php

```
<?php
    include 'conectar.php';
    //recibir datos - tabla persona
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidoP = $_POST['apellidoP'];
    $apellidoM = $_POST['apellidoM'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];

    //recibir datos - tabla cliente
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $contra = $_POST['contra'];
    $foto = $_POST['foto'];
    $persona_idpersona = 0;
    $cliente = 0;


    //consulta para insertar - tabla persona
    $insertarPersona = "INSERT INTO persona(NombrePersona, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, DireccionPersona, SexoPersona) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellidoP', '$apellidoM', '$direccion', '$sexo')";

    //consulta para insertar - tabla cliente
    /* $insertarCliente = "INSERT INTO cliente (Persona_idPersona, NombreUsuario, TipoCliente_idTipoCliente, Correo, Contraseña, Foto) VALUES ('$persona_idpersona´, '$usuario', '$cliente' '$mail', '$contra', '$foto')";*/

    //ejecutar consulta
    $resultado = mysqli_query($cnx, $insertarPersona);

    //condicion para verificar si se registro
    if (!$resultado) {
        echo 'Error no se registro';
    } else {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.alert('USUARIO REGISTRADO EXITOSAMENTE');
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    //cerrar conexion
    mysqli_close($cnx);
?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0,url=inicio_sesion.php">
```

una pregunta como puedo insertar datos a dos tablas con un mismo formulario en php ya que solo me hace la incersion a una sola tabla, no se si sea motivo de las relaciones que no pueda insertar los demas datos

Comment: Debes mostrar el codigo que tenes hasta el momento. Si no es imposible saber que problema tenes

Comment: Me parece extraño querer insertar dos veces los mismos datos en dos tablas distintas ... ¿redundancia de datos? - posiblemente sí. De todos modos, si insistes: para que la segunda consulta también se ejecute, debes pasarla a la base de datos mediante el método `mysqli_query`, tal y como pasas la 1ª: `$resultadoCliente = mysqli_query($cnx, $insertarCliente);` Otra cosa es el mensaje de verificación posterior. Son dos inserciones distintas, puede que una falle y la otra no, puede que las dos fallen, puede que las dos tengan éxito. Tendrás que hacer evaluaciones diferentes por cada una.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias meter las dos query en una funcion, ejecutarlas y preguntar luego

```
if(mysql_query){
  echo "saved data";
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]. Las respuestas deben ser lo mas completas posibles. Que quiere decir meter las dos querys en una funcion?